# Can't get the 'child' & 'parent' communicate together properly

Tags: c, fork, ipc

I am trying to develop a lift simulator application in `C` and for that I am about to use both shared memory and  pipes for inter-porcess communications.
To make my life a bit easier, I have declared two functions named `read_from_pipe` and `write_to_pipe`.

Below is a portion of my `main` code which I need to figure out why it does not behave as expected:

```
01 #include <stdio.h>
02 #include <stdlib.h>
03 #include <string.h>
04 #include <sys/types.h>
05 #include <sys/stat.h>
06 #include <fcntl.h>
07 #include <sys/mman.h>
08 
09 #include "windows.h"
10 
11 #define READ 0
12 #define WRITE 1
13 
14 typedef struct lift
15 {
16         int    winch_control;
17         int    door_control;
18         int    call_buttons;
19         int    lift_buttons;
20         double position;
21         double door_ajar;
22         int    quit;
23         int    reset;
24         int    error;
25 } lift;
26 int main(void)
27 {
28  lift *pLift;
29  pid_t pid;
30  off_t   off = 0;
31  int liftfd, mmlen = sizeof(lift), FIFO[2];;
32  
33  pid = fork();
34  liftfd = open("liftfile", (O_CREAT | O_RDWR), 0666 );
35  pLift = (lift *)mmap( (caddr_t)0, mmlen, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE),  MAP_SHARED, liftfd, off);
36 
37  if (pipe(FIFO))                 // create pipe failed
38  {
39      fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
40      return EXIT_FAILURE;
41  }
42  
43  if (pid == (pid_t)0)            // child process
44  {   
45      close(FIFO[WRITE]);         
46      read_from_pipe(FIFO[READ]);
47      close(FIFO[READ]);
48  }
49  else if (pid < (pid_t)0)        // create fork failed
50  {
51      fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
52      return EXIT_FAILURE;
53  }
54  else                            // parent process
55  {   
56      close(FIFO[READ]);          
57      write_to_pipe(FIFO[WRITE],"UP3" , 56);
58      close(FIFO[WRITE]); 
59  }
60 }
```

`read_from_pipe` subroutine:

```
void read_from_pipe(int fileDescriptr)
{
    FILE *stream;
    int c;
    stream = fdopen(fileDescriptr, "r");
    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

`write_to_pipe` subroutine:

```
void write_to_pipe(int fileDescriptr , char *stateName , int timerValue)
{
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen(fileDescriptr, "w");
    fprintf(stream, "Current system state:\t%s\n", stateName);
    fprintf(stream, "Timer value:\t\t%d\n",timerValue);
    fflush(stream);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

Couple of things that I would like to point out:

- I put line numbers in case if someone wants to refer to a particular
  line. I assume everyone knows how to use column mode in an code
  editor and delete them all for a successful compilation.
- Lots of things in the code might look redundant at first but they are actually being utilised elsewhere in the code. So ignore the
  redundancy if you have picked any.
- I am using CygWin on Windows.

According to line number `57`, my expected result was:

```
Current system state:      UP3
Timer value:               56
```

However I get a blank screen.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the call to `fork()` there are 3 possiblities

1) the returned value is <0, indicating the fork() failed

2) the returned value is 0 indicating the child is executing

3) the returned value is >0 indicating the parent is executing.

Assuming no failure occurred, then both the parent and the child are executing the code following the call to `fork()`.  so both the parent and the child are calling `open()` and `mmap()`.

the returned value from open() and from mmap() both need to be checked to assure the operation(s) were successful.

the mmap() results are not being used in the posted code.

the open() results are not being used in the posted code.

the line: `fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n");` should probably be a call to `perror()` so the system error message is also displayed.

the root of the problem seems to be a race condition.

suggest using `read()` rather than `fgetc()` as read will wait for the desired number of characters,  so will wait for the passed data to be available.  Be sure to check the returned value from `read()` and try again, in a loop until the returned value is 0 (or on an error less than 0)

Comment: You were right. I put everything in an `else` statement after `pipe()` call, and that worked !